# Products and coproducts in posets

Tags: product, category-theory, poset

While reading Bartosz' excellent [Category theory for Programmers](https://bartoszmilewski.com/2014/10/28/category-theory-for-programmers-the-preface/), I got stuck in the second exercise, which deals with products in posets. Given a poset,

```
    b   e
  ↗   ⤭   ↘
a → c   f → h
  ↘   ⤭   ↗
    d   g
```

how can I define a product in the categorical sense? What is categorized by the product of two objects? And what about the coproduct?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Let's have a look at the definition of a product first:

> A product of objects `a` and `b` is the object `c` equipped with morphisms `p :: c -> a` and `q :: c -> b` exist, such that for any other object `c'` (with morphisms `p' :: c' -> a` and `q' :: c' -> b`), there exists a morphism `m :: c' -> c` such that `p' = p . m` and `q' = q . m`.

Remember that a morphism in a poset basically describes the relationship "less than or equal to".

Now the product `c` between two objects `a` and `b` must be an object less than or equal to both `a` and `b`. As an example, lets choose `a` as `e` and `b` as `g` from your graph:

```
    b   e -- this one is a
  ↗   ⤭   ↘
a → c   f → h
  ↘   ⤭   ↗
    d   g -- this one is b
```

Trivially, the first object that comes to mind which is **always** less than or equal to any other object is the smallest object, in this case `a`.

Now is `a` a valid candidate for the product of `e` and `g`? Let's check the definition of product:

Is there a morphism from `a` to `e`? Yes, this exists and can be written as `pₐ = ce . ac` (read as: "first the arrow from a to c, then the arrow from c to e").

Is there a morphism from `a` to `g`? Yes, this exists too and can be written as `qₐ = cg . ac`.

So far so good, the only question left is whether this is the 'best' candidate in the sense that no other object exists such that we can construct a unique isomorphism between `a` and the other candidate?

Looking at the graph, we can see that the object `c` also fulfills the required criteria, with `p = ce` and `q = cg`.

All that is left to do is rank these two objects according to the above definition. We see that there exists a morphism from `a` to `c`. This means `c` has to be the best candidate since we can now define the morphism `m = ac` such that `pₐ = p . m = ce . ac` and `qₐ = q . m = cg . ac`.

So, a product of two objects in a poset is actually the greatest object which is smaller than both (also called the greatest lower bound). It is worth noting that in a total ordering, this corresponds to the function `min(a, b)`, since every object must be relateable to any other object (Wolfram call this [trichotomy law](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TotallyOrderedSet.html)).

---

In analogy to the product definition, the coproduct corresponds to the smallest object greater than or equal to both `a` and `b`. In a total ordering, this corresponds to the maximum of both objects. You can work this one out for yourself.

Comment: In the same sense, can I say that h is a coproduct of e and g?

Comment: @geckos Yes, that is the case. Remember that a coproduct takes two injections: in this case `eh` and `gh` are your injections from `e` (resp. `g`) to `h`.